# plotting two graphs in matlab

Tags: matlab

it's been 5 hours and I'm trying to plot two graphs in matlab but in vain, here is my code

```
x = -pi:.1:pi;

z =(1/(2*pi))*exp(-power(x,2)/2);

y=((n.^(n/2))/fact(n-1))*((x + sqrt(n)).^(n-1))*exp(-sqrt(n)*(x + sqrt(n)));

plot(x,z,'color','r'); hold on;

plot(x,y,'color','b');
```

if there is an other page where I can ask this question please tell me !

Comment: What is `n` in your code?

Comment: you can give any value to n, for example n=10 instead of that the code dosen't work !!

Comment: I get this error message                                         ??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I can only see that you forgot to define `n`. So, either you choose `n=...` or you do a `for` loop and vary `n` from `1..N` and define the upper bound `N`.

Ok. Say `n=10`. Your code will work like this:

```
 n = 10;

 x = -pi:.1:pi;

 z =(1/(2*pi))*exp(-power(x,2)/2);

 y=((n.^(n/2))/factorial(n-1)).*((x + sqrt(n)).^(n-1)).*exp(-sqrt(n)*(x + sqrt(n)));

 plot(x,z,'color','r'); hold on;

 plot(x,y,'color','b');
```

First, `n!` is `factorial` not `fact` in MATLAB. Also, you forgot `.*` multiplication to do vector one by one multiplication.

The above code should work.

[image]

Comment: thank you now it's working !!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Hadamard multiplication rather than matrix:

```
y=((n.^(n/2))/fact(n-1))*((x + sqrt(n)).^(n-1)) .* exp(-sqrt(n)*(x + sqrt(n)));
```

When you see the following error,

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

all you have to do is look at the sizes of the arrays to the left and right of each `*` operator. You will then quickly find the source of the error.

Comment: thanks that was the mistake !